# Z-order while drag and drop between different scene graph branches

Tags: javafx-2

I have an interface where i want to drag an element from a list of elements to a GridPane. The grid and the list are in different branches of the scene graph. Because of that, my draggable Node disapears behind the GridPane, when i want to drag it over the grid.

One possible solution would be to add the draggable node to a frontmost Pane, where it will be in front of all other nodes. Unfortunately this means i have to remove the node from its old position before i know that the drag and drop gesture will be successfull, which leads to all kinds of additional code.

Is there a way to have a node rendered in front of all other nodes without changing its position in the scene graph?

Comment: toFront() moves this Node to the front of its _sibling nodes_ in terms of z-order. Unfortunately thats not enough for different branches (ancestors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the "draggable Node" actually being moved around by the cursor?  If so, you could create an Image from the node and drag that around?

Comment: Great idea and it works.There is only one problem left. I use Scene#snapshot(WritableImage image) to create an image of the whole scene und set the viewport of the ImageView to the bounds of the dragged node. Unfortunately the image is verry blurred. Any idea how to create an unblurred image?

Comment: I'm not sure without looking at the code, it sounds like the image may have been given the wrong dimensions so it would have been resized. But it's just a guess.

Comment: I use snapshot(null) which creates a new WriteableImage instance. Therefore i guess the dimensions are ok.

Comment: You might need to take the snapshot method that takes a SnapshotParameters and set the viewport to that of the node you are writing.  The one that takes only a WritableImage takes a snapshot of the entire scene.

Comment: Found a solution at [how-to-get-an-accurate-image-of-a-node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176060/how-to-get-an-accurate-image-of-a-node)